# Find & Replace in blogger

Tags: find-and-replace, api

(I just learnt that [Yahoo are shutting down Geocities](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/04/23/yahoo-quietly-pulls-the-plug-on-geocities/), this is a bummer as I used my account there to host two icons, in the days when Blogger didn't upload gifs. Now those two icons are referenced in every one of my 600+ posts).

Blogger doesn't have a "Find & Replace in all posts" function. I'm wondering about using the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/) to hack something together, and wondered if anyone has already tried playing with the API, if there are any tips or things to avoid. Also if there isn't a sneaky shortcut (like switching to ftp, doing the replace locally then switching back?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could export your blog (it's an atom format), make the changes on your computer, and import it again.

Comment: Sounds quite good, but I don't know if I've got the guts to try that! Can't determine if import will replace or append all the posts.

Comment: I don't know either (never tried). I guess you could always create a second blog as sandbox and give it a try. Let us know of your success...

Comment: ...or failure :) [will do, though quite tempted to give the API a try anyway]

Comment: Worked for a blog with 3 posts, brief moment of panic when Import Page froze (F5 fixed that). It won't import duplicates, so you have to delete all first. This is very scary for 630 posts...

Comment: Also note that it 'hid' all my draft posts, so I thought for a moment I had lost them all, but it was just the list filter settings.

Comment: Past 1000 posts now, and still haven't dared to try :)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could automate this with a python script pretty easily. It's just http forms to edit blogger right? You'll probably need to http sniff your cookies and headers and then just duplicate it all using urllib2. Figure out how cycle through all your blogger blog posts edit pages, grab the text from that input box and then search and replace with python.